# Cannot connect self-hosted Linux VM to Azure DevOps

Tags: virtual-machines, deployment, azure-devops, agent, pipelining

I am trying to set up a docker deployment process with Azure DevOps using a self-hosted Linux VM as a deployment target. It seems that I must install the AzurePipelines agent on the target Linux VM first, however it always stalls at the "Connect" stage. Since I am doing this for the first time, I suspect that I have missed some crucial step in the process.

What I have done so far:

- created an Azure DevOps project with a build pipeline that successfully pushes a docker image to AzureCR
- created an admin user on a (3rd party hosted) Linux VM VM (have tried CentOS 7 64bit and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit -- same result)
- created an Environment in DevOps Pipelines
- tried to add a resource to the new environment by copying the provided script to an SSH command prompt on the VM. --> download and unpacking successful, but ends with error:

  ```
   ./config.sh: Zeile 86:  4947 Speicherzugriffsfehler  ./bin/Agent.Listener configure "$@"
   sudo: ./svc.sh: Befehl nicht gefunden
   sudo: ./svc.sh: Befehl nicht gefunden
  ```
- manually run `~/azagent$ sudo bin/installdependencies.sh` --> finished successfully
- manually run `~/azagent$ sudo ./config.sh` --> following output, after that it stalls and does nothing; no VM appears in Azure Pipelines environment resources:

```
  ___                      ______ _            _ _
 / _ \                     | ___ (_)          | (_)
/ /_\ \_____   _ _ __ ___  | |_/ /_ _ __   ___| |_ _ __   ___  ___
|  _  |_  / | | | '__/ _ \ |  __/| | '_ \ / _ \ | | '_ \ / _ \/ __|
| | | |/ /| |_| | | |  __/ | |   | | |_) |  __/ | | | | |  __/\__ \
\_| |_/___|\__,_|_|  \___| \_|   |_| .__/ \___|_|_|_| |_|\___||___/
                                   | |
        agent v2.175.2             |_|          (commit 5c4925c)


>> Endbenutzer-Lizenzbestimmungen:

Für das Erstellen von Quellen aus einem TFVC-Repository muss die Zustimmung zu den Team Explorer Everywhere-Endbenutzer-Lizenzbestimmungen erfolgen. Dieser Schritt ist für das Erstellen von Quellen aus Git-Repositorys nicht erforderlich.

Eine Kopie der Team Explorer Everywhere-Endbenutzer-Lizenzbestimmungen finden Sie hier:
  /home/admin/azagent/externals/tee/license.html

Geben Sie (J/N) Den Team Explorer Everywhere-Lizenzbedingungen jetzt zustimmen? ein (Drücken Sie die EINGABETASTE, um N). > J

>> Verbinden:

Server-URL eingeben > https://dev.azure.com/[~~~~~]
Geben Sie Authentifizierungstyp ein (Drücken Sie die EINGABETASTE, um PAT). >
Persönliches Zugriffstoken eingeben > ****************************************************
```

Of course, I have inserted a proper name in the URL instead of `[~~~~~]`.

On a side note, I was able to supply the very same VM with a managed identity by installing the Azure CLI as described in [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication-managed-identity), but this does not solve my problem; it just rules out connectivity problems.

What am I missing?